# Who is the owner of a record in DynamoDB if record is created by post confirmation trigger in AWS cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

So i have a post confirmation trigger in AWS cognito that inserts a signed up user into my dynamoDB table.

Issue is that im using AWS Amplify & AppSync to query that table via graphql. There are @auth directives that i want to add onto this table to allow only the actual user to edit their user metadata in dynamoDB. My question is, who is the owner of that record if it was actually created via the post confirmation lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such information is **not stored** in the record itself. So who uploaded a record into DynamoDB (DDB) database is not something that DDB checks and enforces. For that you would have to design a custom solution, a keep a separate attribute in the record indicating entity that created the record through your app.

However, DDB allows for [granular IAM access control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html) to individual records or even its attributes. This could allow you to craft IAM policies that allow access to individual users only, through  IAM substitution variables, e.g. `${www.amazon.com:user_id}`.

Comment: Thanks! Managed to read up a bit more on it here: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/auth#static-group-authorization. Added a field to record the "owner" as you suggested and worked with the link above to implement a working solution.

Comment: Is this the same for Storage?  I want anyone in an "Admin" user group, to be able to access a protected file in storage.  But I'm not sure where to get the owner of the files id from, since I need that info to build up the "Key" of the file, to get it from storage.